# OpenGL defect - undesirable interpolation

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, glfw, glew

I am trying to render Utah teapot using Bèzier Surfaces and kind of succeeded in that. Yet, I have some defects that is totally undesirable. As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMXNZ.png), the teapot looks OK, but there exists some unnecessary 'interpolation'. What do you think that may have caused this?  By the way, when I write the object into a .ply file, I could managed to open it using meshlab with no problem and no defect. Lastly, I'm using Xcode as my development environment.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

**EDIT:** Some parts of the code are added. First of all, the control points and the patches used are retrieved from [this](https://www.computer.org/csdl/mags/cg/1987/01/mcg1987010008.pdf) old paper.

```
struct position3D { GLfloat x, y, z; };
struct position3D teapot_cp_vertices[] = {
    // 1
    { 1.4   ,   0.0   ,  2.4 },
    { 1.4   ,  -0.784 ,  2.4 },
    { 0.784 ,  -1.4   ,  2.4 },
    { 0.0   ,  -1.4   ,  2.4 },
                 .
                 .
                 .
}

#define TEAPOT_NB_PATCHES 32
#define ORDER 3
unsigned short teapot_patches[][ORDER + 1][ORDER + 1] =
{
    // rim
    { { 1,   2,   3,   4 },{ 5,   6,   7,   8 },{ 9,  10,  11,  12 },{ 13,  14,  15,  16, } },
    { { 4,  17,  18,  19 },{ 8,  20,  21,  22 },{ 12,  23,  24,  25 },{ 16,  26,  27,  28, } },
    { { 19,  29,  30,  31 },{ 22,  32,  33,  34 },{ 25,  35,  36,  37 },{ 28,  38,  39,  40, } },
    { { 31,  41,  42,   1 },{ 34,  43,  44,   5 },{ 37,  45,  46,   9 },{ 40,  47,  48,  13, } },
       ...
       ...
       ...
   } }
}
```

All the points and patches can be found in the mentioned paper.

The vertices and the triangles used to render the teapot is calculated using:

```
int factorial(int n)
{
    assert(n >= 0);
    return (n == 1 || n == 0) ? 1 : factorial(n - 1) * n;
}
float binomial_coefficient(int i, int n) {
    assert(i >= 0); assert(n >= 0);
    return 1.0f * factorial(n) / (factorial(i) * factorial(n-i));
}
float bernstein_polynomial(int i, int n, float u) {
    return binomial_coefficient(i, n) * powf(u, i) * powf(1-u, n-i);
}
void build_control_points_k(int p, struct position3D control_points_k[][ORDER+1]) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= ORDER; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= ORDER; j++) {
            control_points_k[i][j] = teapot_cp_vertices[teapot_patches[p][i][j] - 1];

        }
    }
}

Vertex compute_position(struct position3D control_points_k[][ORDER+1], float u, float v) {
    Vertex result = *new Vertex();
    for (int i = 0; i <= ORDER; i++) {
        float poly_i = bernstein_polynomial(i, ORDER, u);
        for (int j = 0; j <= ORDER; j++) {
            float poly_j = bernstein_polynomial(j, ORDER, v);
            result.x += poly_i * poly_j * control_points_k[i][j].x;
            result.y += poly_i * poly_j * control_points_k[i][j].y;
            result.z += poly_i * poly_j * control_points_k[i][j].z;
            result.r = 0; //default colour 
            result.g = 0;
            result.b = 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
#define RESU 10 //resolution in u axis
#define RESV 10 //resolution in v axis

void Object3D::build_teapot() {
    vlist = new Vertex[TEAPOT_NB_PATCHES * RESU*RESV]; //vertex list
    tlist = new Triangle[TEAPOT_NB_PATCHES * (RESU-1)*(RESV-1) * 2]; //triangle list

    //calculate vertices
    for (int p = 0; p < TEAPOT_NB_PATCHES; p++) {
        struct position3D control_points_k[ORDER+1][ORDER+1];
        build_control_points_k(p, control_points_k);
        for (int ru = 0; ru <= RESU-1; ru++) {
            float u = 1.0 * ru / (RESU-1);
            for (int rv = 0; rv <= RESV-1; rv++) {
                float v = 1.0 * rv / (RESV-1);
                vlist[p*RESU*RESV + ru*RESV + rv] = compute_position(control_points_k, u, v);
                vlist[p*RESU*RESV + ru*RESV + rv].r = 1.0 * p / TEAPOT_NB_PATCHES;
                vlist[p*RESU*RESV + ru*RESV + rv].g = 1.0 * p / TEAPOT_NB_PATCHES;
                vlist[p*RESU*RESV + ru*RESV + rv].b = 0.7;
            }
        }
    }
//calculate triangle vertex orders or namely triangles
int n = 0;
Triangle tmpTrg = *new Triangle();
tmpTrg.nverts = 3;
for (int p = 0; p < TEAPOT_NB_PATCHES; p++) {
    for (int ru = 0; ru < RESU-1; ru++)
        for (int rv = 0; rv < RESV-1; rv++) {
            // ABCD is a square
            // triangle in the order ABC is the first one
            tmpTrg.verts = new int[tmpTrg.nverts];
            tmpTrg.verts[0] = p*RESU*RESV +  ru   *RESV +  rv   ;
            tmpTrg.verts[1] = p*RESU*RESV +  ru   *RESV + (rv+1);
            tmpTrg.verts[2] = p*RESU*RESV + (ru+1)*RESV + (rv+1);
            tlist[n] = tmpTrg;
            n++;
            // triangle in the order CDA is the second one
            tmpTrg.verts = new int[tmpTrg.nverts];
            tmpTrg.verts[0] = p*RESU*RESV + (ru+1)*RESV + (rv+1);
            tmpTrg.verts[1] = p*RESU*RESV + (ru+1)*RESV +  rv   ;
            tmpTrg.verts[2] = p*RESU*RESV +  ru   *RESV +  rv   ;

            tlist[n] = tmpTrg;
            n++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is GL initialisation function:

```
void init(int w, int h)
{
    // Init GLFW
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    // macOSX requirement :
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(w, h, "OpenGLTeapot", nullptr, nullptr); // Windowed
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    // Initialize GLEW to setup the OpenGL Function pointers
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    // Define the viewport dimensions
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    // Enable depth test
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

**EDIT 2 :** I tried to run the code on a Windows computer using Visual Studio15 as and there is no defect like this. Does anybody have any idea about what may cause such a stupid problem?

**EDIT 3:** Here is the object creation code:

```
void Object3D::CreateObject()
{

    int attributeCount = 6;
    vertexCount        = TEAPOT_NB_PATCHES * RESU*RESV;
    triangleCount      = TEAPOT_NB_PATCHES * (RESU-1)*(RESV-1) * 2;
    build_teapot();

    //Bind the vertex and index buffers
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    // Bind our Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set our buffers and pointers.
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    //Convert our vertex list into a continuous array, copy the vertices into the vertex buffer.
    float* vertexData = new float[vertexCount * attributeCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++)
        memcpy(&vertexData[i*attributeCount], 
            vlist[i].getAsArray(), sizeof(float)*attributeCount);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*attributeCount*vertexCount, vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    //Copy the index data found in the list of triangles into the element array buffer (index array)
    //We are using a triangles, so we need triangleCount * 3 indices.
    int* indexData = new int[triangleCount * 3];
    for (int i = 0; i < triangleCount; i++)
        memcpy(&indexData[i * 3], tlist[i].verts, sizeof(int) * 3);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(int)*3*triangleCount, indexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    // Position attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, attributeCount * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    // Color attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, attributeCount * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    // Unbind VAO
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // Delete temporary buffers
    delete[] vertexData;
    delete[] indexData;
}
```

And the main function:

```
int main()
{
    int screenWidth = 800;
    int screenHeight = 600;
    init(screenWidth, screenHeight);
    std::vector<Object3D*> listOfObjects;


    Object3D* pObj = new Object3D();


    pObj->CreateObject();
    listOfObjects.push_back(pObj);

    //Create the shaders. 
    Shader shader(VertexShaderPath, FragmentShaderPath);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
        // Clear the colorbuffer
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Use the shader
        shader.Use();
        // Transformations
        // Create camera transformation
        glm::mat4 view;
        glm::vec3 cameraPos = glm::vec3(0.0f, 150.0f, 100.0f);
        glm::vec3 cameraTarget = glm::vec3(0.0, 80.0f, 20.0f);
        glm::vec3 cameraUp = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        view = glm::lookAt(cameraPos, cameraTarget, cameraUp);
        // Create projection transformation
        glm::mat4 projection;
        projection = glm::perspective<float>(90.0, (float)screenWidth / (float)screenHeight, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
        // Get the uniform locations
        GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "model");
        GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "view");
        GLint projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader.Program, "projection");
        // Pass the view and projection matrices to the shaders
        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
        // Put the bottom of the object on XZ plane and scale it up
        pObj->modelMatrix = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(30.0f));
        pObj->modelMatrix = glm::rotate(pObj->modelMatrix, -90.0f, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f,0.0f));
        for (auto pObj : listOfObjects)
        {
            glBindVertexArray(pObj->VAO);

            glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(pObj->modelMatrix));
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (pObj->vertexCount) * 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
            //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 50, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
            glBindVertexArray(0);
        }
        // Swap the buffers

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    }
    for (auto pObj : listOfObjects)
    {
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &pObj->VAO);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &pObj->VBO);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &pObj->EBO);
        delete pObj;
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to refine your question with additional information, such as code and error message to describe your programming problem.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is, there is no error message. That's why I didn't add any source code. I thought of sharing the whole code, yet since that can easily be given as a homework, I didn't want to be a part of any plagiarism attempt.

Comment: It's likely a division by zero accident. Without seeing any code nobody will be able to help you. Nor anybody wants to see all of your code. You should instead restrict the problem to a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Although I don't think that the cause is a division by zero accident, I have added some parts that may contain such a problem. I looked for such a case and failed to find one.

Comment: Nothing stands out as incorrect to me, and the fact that you are writing good ply files and running fine on another machine suggests the problem is in the GL rendering code. Can you show your mesh render code?

Comment: I have added the related code parts to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be about the offset of glDrawElements function. When I changed that line to:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (listOfObjects[i]->vertexCount) * 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)(sizeof(Vertex)));
```

it renders properly.